# Остановка действия в Delphi

Tags: delphi

```
for i :=0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
begin
...
end;
```

Есть запущенный процесс. Как его остановить?
Кидаю на форму кнопку "STOP" и делаю:

```
break
```

Но выдаёт ошибку при компиляции:

> [DCC Error] Unit2.pas(66): E2097 BREAK or CONTINUE outside of loop

Как реализовать остановку действующего процесса с возможностью его продолжения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, одной простой командой вы этого не сделаете.

Почитайте, что делает break, как работают циклы, потоки, события  и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Вам что сделать-то надо? :

```
Есть запущенный процесс. Как его остановить?
```

В качестве кода приводите цикл, вместо ожидаемой апишной функции....

Так вот, знайте, что это:

```
for i :=0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
begin
...
end;
```

не процесс =), а цикл, остановить который( как я понял ) можно брейком:

```
break;
```